Sorted set precondition to check that the new addition has the highest score
We are working on a solution where we want to add a new entity only if the score of this new entity is the highest among all the entities in the existing redis sorted set.
Is there a precondition check that would guarantee this behavior.

You can solve it with Lua scripting:
-- add_only_large_enough.lua
local key = KEYS[1]
local member = ARGV[1]
local score = ARGV[2]

local largest_item = redis.call('zrange', key, -1, -1, 'withscores')
if next(largest_item) == nil or largest_item[2] < score then
    redis.call('zadd', key, score, member)
    return 1
else
    return 0
end

Run it like this: redis-cli --eval add_only_large_enough.lua sorted_set_key , member score
